# Getting randomly selected cells in a table

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm working on a word ribbon *MS Office application in VS2010 using C#*.

When I have a table in the document, I want to add some text in randomly selected cells of the table when a button on the ribbon is pressed..

The problem is, everytime I select random number of cells the `WrdApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Cells` gets only the last selected cell.

Here's the code :

```
  foreach (Cell myCell in WrdApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Cells)
  {
      myCell.Range.Text = "text" + myCell.Range.Text
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `WrdApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Cells` contains more than one item?

Comment: totally , u can give it a try on simple word application